# Isometry is equivalence relation on Lorentzian manifold?

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, relativity, topology

[Proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isometry_of_Metric_Spaces_is_Equivalence_Relation) says isometry is an equivalence relation on metric spaces, and e.g. Minkowski space is a metric space - but as a metric space its metric is not the Minkowski metric (see [this S.E. question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526171/is-minkowski-space-not-a-metric-space)).

So the question is: what is the proof (it seems natural that it should be true) that an isometry on a Lorentzian manifold is an equivalence relation?

Comment: An isometry of (semi)Riemannian manifolds , by definition, is a diffeomorphism whose differential preserves the (Lorentzian) scalar product in the tangent space. The identity map is therefore an isometry. The inverse of an isometry is an isometry, the composition of two isometries is an isomtery. So, for a pair of Lorentzian manifold, to be connected by an ismometry is a reflexive, symmetric and transitive relation: an equivalence relation.

Comment: You are using the wrong definition of isometry (for this context) that of metric spaces.

Comment: However referring to the so-called Lorentizian distance of temporally oriented manifolds, it is possible to recast a notion of isometry similar to that of metrical spaces, with analogous properties....

Comment: Thanks Valter, I was hoping you'd see this but didn't want to bother you directly :) If I was using the wrong def and should prefer the one you just gave, how does one specify which def one is using? A bit puzzled by the need to recast the notion. What am I missing: distance is distance...(?). Nb I'm looking at isometry etc. between the boundaries of two excised sets as discussed in the question you answered previously.

Comment: Simply they are two different notions. A Lorentzian manifold is **not** a metrical space and there is no way to construct such a structure naturally associated to a Lorentzian manifold,  so you cannot use the definition of isometery of metrical spaces. On a Lorentzian manifold there is no distance function constructed out of the differential and metrical structure...

Comment: Got it; I keep forgetting that d(x,y) =0 does not imply x=y with a Lorentzian metric and therefore does not fulfill the def. of metric space.

Comment: If the manifold were Riemannian and connected, then you would have both structures and the two notions of isometry would coincide (under suitable hypotheses essentially the ones of Hopf-Rinow theorem). The distance $d(p,q)$ as a metrical space is defined as the *infimum* of the length of the curves joining two given points $p,q$...

Comment: In Lorentzian manifolds how do you define $d(x,y)$?  (Yes, you are right, also if you were able to define it $d(x,y)=0$ would not imply $x=y$).

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question? If not, other than this I don't know: any two points can be connected by null curves so sup not inf. Keen to know where I might be adrift or incomplete...

Comment: No, it was not rhetorical! It is a problem. There is a well known candidate (the "Lorentzian distance") using the **supremum** of the length of causal curves joining causally connected points, and assuming *by definition* that the "distance" of non-causally connected points is zero.  The notion of "distance" arising this way has properties very different from the distance in metrical spaces. For instance the triangular inequality does not hold and a converse inequality holds....

Comment: I was not aware of the Lorentzian Distance function before. I don't think I want to use that because I would like the isometry under consideration to respect all separations: if I use the isom as equivalence I want $M / ~$ to be well-defined i.e. to require isometry. A bit hard to be clear doing this on my phone...  just want to say that if you remove "holes" by quotienting  identified surfaces better be isometric :)

Comment: I do not know, too complicated :(. And now I must stop reading. Bye